# How to use the Aggregate Hadoop package to find the minimum value across all keys?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Hadoop through Cloudera.
 I need to find the minimum value and the key, across few text files

The text files (*.txt) are of this format containing key value pairs:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

The output should be :

```
A   1
```

But I am getting:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

as the code is giving the minimum value based on the keys 'A', 'B' and 'C' respectively. Is there a way to use the aggregate package to be able to get the output as the minimum value is:

```
A   1
```

This is the mapper.py.

```
import sys

def generateLongMinToken(word,value):    
    return "LongValueMin:" + word + "\t" + value

def main(argv):                   
   line = sys.stdin.readline()
   try:
        while line:
        word, value =  line.rstrip().split() # remove leading and trailing whitespace  # split the line into words   
        print generateLongMinToken(word,value)
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
   except "end of file":
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main(sys.argv)
```

And this is the hadoop command :

```
 hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file mapper.py -mapper mapper.py \
-reducer aggregate \
-input /user/cloudera/gutenberg/min/* \
-output /user/cloudera/gutenberg/min_output
```

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen , thanks for editing my question!

Comment: That's just [one of the ways to contribute to Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).